# Как можно сделать preloader,чтобы он работал пока идет fetch запрос,

Tags: javascript, api, fetch

Доброе утро. Не могу понять как в fetch запросе сделать, чтобы до того как запрос отправился- работал прелодер. Я на писал следкющий код, но прелодер не включается.Буду рад любой помощи.

```
// Отправляем данные на сервер с помощью Fetch API
 

     fetch("/", {
        method: "POST",
        body: formData 
      })
    
      .then(function(response) {
     document.querySelector("#spiner").classList.remove("display-none");-включаю отображение прелодера
     document.querySelector("#button__title").classList.add("display-none");
    if (response.ok) {
     document.querySelector("#spiner").classList.add("display-none");
     document.querySelector("#button__title").classList.remove("display-none");
        document.getElementById('copyForm').reset();
     document.getElementById('modal-thank-you').classList.remove("display-none");
     document.querySelector(".pre-footer__row").classList.add("display-none");
    }
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.error("Ошибка:", error);
        
      });
    });
```

Comment: Включать "отображение прелодера" имеет смысл перед вызовом `fetch`. Можно даже делать такое с неким `setTimeout`, поскольку можно получить данные достаточно быстро и "моргать" лишний раз "прелоадером" смысла особого нет. При получении данных можно `setTimeout` удалять и выключать "прелоадер"...

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!